# Facebook Login using Facebook SDK

Tags: ios

I used this concept to Login.

```
-(void)LoginButtonTapped
{

    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"friends_email",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown",@"user_location",@"friends_birthday",@"friends_location",@"friends_hometown", nil];

    [[delegate facebook]authorize:permissions];

    [FBSession.activeSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                    NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"success");

        // [signinbutton setHidden:YES];


         }

     }];


    [permissions release];
}
```

but,Suppose if i close the Login window without Login,then it does not display Login Window again.

It showed this Error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: an attempt was made to open an already opened or closed session'
```

Any Idea Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the errors with the `FBErrorUtility`, it will call when you close / Cancel the Facebook Login

```
// Handle possible errors that can occur during login

- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error {

  if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
    NSLog(@"user cancelled login");
  }

}
```

There are lot of other errors which can occur during Facebook Login
refer, see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors) for more info.